# Build error in FBSDKLoginButton.m file after updating FacebookLogin Cocoapods

Tags: cocoapods, facebook-login, swift4.1, xcode9.4, fbsdkloginkit

I just updated my FacebookCore and FacebookLogin Cocoapods, am using XCode 9.4.1, and Swift 4.1, and I'm now getting a build error in my FBSDKLoginButton.m file.

[image]

I tried updating and installing all pods again, without any dependency issues. But I just can't get my project to build anymore. Any leads would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

OK, I don't know why, but declaring the version explicitly after the pod name helped fix it like this:

```
pod 'FBSDKCoreKit', '~> 4.35.0'
```

If someone can tell me why, I'd love to know.